# Apache Wamp [error]

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, ssl

This question and its answers transfered to:

[This location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29009812/apache-wamp-error-20024the-given-path-is-misformatted-or-contained-invalid-c/29009859#29009859)

Comment: Don't know if it's a copy/paste error, but look at the double quotes used to quote the path, they're not "straight quotes" (like those used the line below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be related with the "double quotes" you used.

The error says : `\x93C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.11/logs/ssl_request.log\x94`.
We can see that the invalid characters are the first and the last ones. It corresponds with your "double quotes".

Use this kind of quotes : `"` instead of `“`.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the double quotes and the extra space between the backslash and the double quote (\ "):

```
CustomLog C:/wamp/bin/apache/Apache2.2.11/logs/ssl_request.log \"%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
```